# VB6 DODB Recordset can't access more than 5 tables

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb6, adodb

This is a VB6 question as I am currently working on a feature that calls a MSSQL stored procedure which return 7 tables. I store it in a ADODB recordset but when I use the NextRecordSet function I can't access past my 6th table, is this a limitation with the ADODB in VB6, the same stored procedure was used in VB.Net in an ASP.NET website and worked fine.

Comment: If this is a VB6 question, then why do you use the VB.NET tag?

Comment: Because I have used the same procedure in VB.Net and worked with no problems

Comment: But I also need to implement in an older application written in vb6

Comment: It is not an ADODB limitation. We are currently using the same logic to access 11 recordsets returned by a single SQL query.